# Error Code: 1146. Table 'fe539.t' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with the issue below in MySQL

The issue rises at alias 'T'

```
select course_id, sec_id, enrollment 
from (
    select course_id, sec_id, count(ID) as enrollment
    from section natural join takes
    where semester = 'Fall' and year =2009
    group by course_id, sec_id
) as T
where enrollment = (select max(enrollment) from T);
```

Comment: Natural joins are an abomination - much more understandable to use an explicit join (for the reader and the optimizer).

Comment: You should read up on mysql order of execution. The fact that the select comes after the where in the order of execution is relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might get away with something like the following if you don't have any draws.

```
select course_id, sec_id, count(*) as enrollment
        from section s
        join takes t on s.sec_id = t.course_id
        where semester = 'Fall' and year =2009
        group by course_id, sec_id 
        order by count(*) desc 
        limit 1 
;
```